# How to use wine to run Microsoft office

Tags: wine

Do all windows applications work in ubuntu with wine? Can I use Microsoft office in ubuntu using wine application.

Comment: no not everything will work with wine but these days most things do as for microsoft office here is a link to the winehq user reported tests (note this site has alot of useful info)(https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?iId=31&sClass=application)

Comment: Not all windows applications work in Wine. You can check https://appdb.winehq.org/ for detail if any application run in wine or not.  As per this page https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?iId=31&sClass=application >> various versions of Microsoft office installed perfectly. But still using individual component you have to check.